# Log4j is not able to write the files to jetty logs directory

Tags: java, ubuntu, log4j, jetty

I have an application running on Jetty 8.0.

I have configured the log4j to write the logs to a file. Here is the configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d%-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <param name="File" value="someLogFileName.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d%-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.somename">
        <level value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I have even set the permission for the user which is running the Jetty instance.

The log directory of the Jetty has following permissions:

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 someuser somegroupuser   4096 Feb 18 05:27 logs
```

But still getting exception.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: someLogFileName.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:295)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseCategory(DOMConfigurator.java:436)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:999)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:867)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:755)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:891)
    at com.zedo.rtbui.server.RtbUILogger.<init>(RtbUILogger.java:22)
    at com.zedo.rtbui.server.RtbUILogger.init(RtbUILogger.java:28)
    at com.zedo.rtbui.server.InitServiceImpl.initialize(InitServiceImpl.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:907)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Can someone guide me on what could be done to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your log4j configuration isn't specifying what directory to write that log file to.

Change

```
<param name="File" value="someLogFileName.log" />
```

to

```
<param name="File" value="${jetty.home}/logs/someLogFileName.log" />
```

Comment: When I changed this it instead added a directory named "${jetty.home}" than assuming it as path to home directory of jetty installation. I am   using Ubuntu.

Comment: `${jetty.home}` is defined by the standard jetty-distribution startup procedures.  Are you running with the jetty-distribution from eclipse.org or are you using the rebundled / repackaged jetty from ubuntu?  Just note that the core problem, Where does this log get created?, and the solution of providing a full path to the log4j configuration is still present.

Answer (score 1):

Without specifying the absolute path, log4j will try to create the file in the directory where the java process is started. I guess it's jetty home in your case.

You can define a system property to change this behavior:

- through code, make sure it runs before log4j initialization

  System.setProperty ("WORKDIR", WORKDIR);
- through command line

  java  -DWORKDIR=WORKDIR

Use this system property in  you log4j configuration:

```
  <param name="File" value="${WORKDIR}/someLogFileName.log" />
```